# Craft3 - Getting rid of /web in my URL

Tags: craft3, siteurl

I am very new to craft. installed craft3 very long ago, as a beginner, and trying to solve a long-lasted-issue with my url.

my goal:

- Change my base url from [www.mywebsite.com/web](http://www.mywebsite.com/web) to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)

- At the moment [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) shows 403 forbidden error.

My directory structure looks as below. As you can see, I installed craft only under public_html/mywebsite.com. I cannot move the files in /mywebsite.com into /public_html folder.

I researched and tried to follow [this article](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29085/how-do-i-get-rid-of-web-in-url) however quiet unsure with the different folder structure I have.
Just in case I moved index.html file to the /mywebsite.com root, and at least forbidden error was gone while only blanc page was loaded.
I had the feeling that I could do something with index.php file to redefine`('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));`. However also not sure what to write..

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!
[image: my directory structure]

Answer (score 1):

This knowledge base article on [moving Craft’s files below the webroot](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/moving-craft-files) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to change the domains root directory from ../public_html to ../public_html/web, so that only the "web" directory is accessible from outside. This is also recommendable from a security standpoint.